# Order facet by semester and year

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to order a ggplot graph using facet_grid, example:

Sorry , I know that my data its no logic but its ok to show my problem with the facets...

In my real data I dont have this data, only i use this block below to get my data in this example:

```
################ only to get data in my example ######################


    set.seed(12345)
    Date <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2013/1/1"), "6 months" )
    Y <- rnorm(n=length(Date), mean=100, sd=1)
    df <- data.frame(Date, Y)
    df$Year <- format(df$Date, "%Y")
    df$Sem <- format(df$Date, "%b")
    df$Sem <- gsub("ene.", "1S",df$Sem )
    df$Sem <- gsub("jul.", "2S",df$Sem )
    df$MonthYear <- format(df$Date, "%b-%Y")

     ##############        o          #################
```

Variables that are in my real data are:

Sem, Semester and  Y

I extract the year to sort in my second try:

```
    df=df %>%
    mutate(extract_year= sub('.*(\\d{4}).*', '\\1', MonthYear)) 

    df$Semester=paste0(df$Sem,df$extract_year)
```

#Here I tried to sort the facet but I failed:

```
    df2 <- within(df,Semester <- ordered(Semester, levels = rev(sort(unique(Semester)))))

    df2 %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = Y )) + 
    geom_bar() +
    facet_grid(Semester~.)
```

[image: example]

I tried also with:

```
    df2 %>%
    arrange(extract_year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = Y )) + 
    geom_bar() +
    facet_grid(Semester~.)
```

I would like get this order:

1S2010/2S2010/1S2011/2S2011/1S2012/2S2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to set the order of the levels in your desired order. One option to achieve that would be to `arrange` the data in your desired order and make use of `forcats::fct_inorder` to set the order of the levels of your `Semester` variable.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

## Make Semester variable in the desired format
df <- mutate(df, Sem = recode(Sem, Jan = "1S", Jul = "2S"),
             Semester = paste0(Sem, Year))

# Arrange and set order
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(gsub("^(\\dS)(\\d{4})$", "\\2\\1", Semester)) %>%
  mutate(Semester = forcats::fct_inorder(Semester))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Y )) + 
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(Semester~.)
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, `mutate(Semester = forcats::fct_reorder(Semester, Date))`

Comment: @JonSpring Thx. 2Absolutely. That's the shortest way in this case.

Comment: Thanks but I dont have df$Date in my real data, I comment that in my example

Comment: @RodrigoBadilla It would be easier to help you if you provided example data which resembles the structure of your real data. Anyway. The approach is the same. Arrange and set the order. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks @stefan for you help, I fix my problem with you post. I know that its not easy with my help but I try to replicate it.

Comment: @RodrigoBadilla. You are welcome. In know that it's not easy to provide good example data. But one gets better on that. (; Best S.